# Raspberry Pi Ethernet not connecting

Tags: raspberry-pi, ethernet

I have just installed Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi and I booted it up with it attached to a monitor, keyboard, and ethernet. I can successfully log in, but when I run ifconfig, it only shows the lo interface (eth0 does not show up at all). It is plugged into the router via ethernet and the lights by the ethernet outlets are on for both the router and the raspberry pi. It also does not show up as a connected device on the router admin screen.

Since this is a new Pi, I'm not sure if the problem is hardware or software, do I need to do anything special to connect it to ethernet?

Comment: Offtopic. Not a programming question. We are not general hardware tech support. That being said, did you configure the interface for dhcp or set a static ip?

Comment: this belongs to raspberrypi.stackexchange.com , stackeoverflow is for problems with direct programming context see stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I configured it for dhcp, which was the default.

Comment: Thank you, I will put it on raspberrypi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

```
ifconfig -a
```

should return all the interface available in your system( generally speaking), you will see eth0 which is down, to bring it up:

```
ifconfig eth0 up
```

then you can configure eth0 either manually or using dhcp.

Comment: I got a `SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted` after running `ifconfig eth0 up`

Comment: It means the user you ran the command with does not have the permission, try sudo ifconfig ...